# What is the simplest command I could use to test that my wallet unlocking process works properly?

Tags: bitcoind, wallet, json-rpc, testnet, testing

I simply want to unit test that my lock/unlock process works well on an encrypted wallet.

What would be the easiest command I could send (that doesn't involve sending coins) to actually validate if my wallet is locked or unlocked? Can I try to sign a dummy transaction for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sign a message using the `signmessage` command. Note that this only works if you are using `legacy` addresses (Bitcoin Core currently defaults to `p2sh-segwit` addresses which cannot be used to sign a message). You an get a legacy address using:

```
bitcoin-cli getnewaddres "" legacy
```

If the wallet is locked, you won't be able to sign a message.